# Does offering a bounty on someone else's question make you the owner?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, bounties, ownership

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I'm sure I could answer this myself by starting one, but I don't want to risk it quite yet.

Basically I'm trying to understand, if I were to post a bounty on someone else's question (because I want to drive up input/would like to know the answer) do I get notifications as if I was the OP, or do I need to now follow up on the question manually to verify when answers/comments come in?

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe: I don't see this specifically mentioned anywhere in that FAQ. Maybe you should add it if you want to close it as a duplicate. ;)

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe - Yeah, I saw that link before I posted, this point wasn't in there so I figured I'd ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't become the owner and you don't get any notifications you wouldn't get otherwise (i.e. comments to your comments, comments on an answer etc...).

If you want to, you can get notifications by making the question a favourite.

Comment: Does making the question a favorite give you all the same notifications as if you were the owner of the question? I've favorited a few but never seen a notification (probably cause they were stagnant)

Comment: @Mike - Not sure about all, but you get notified (in the favourite tab) when new comments and answers are posted.

Comment: Just tested it out, you don't. Oh well. Thanks for your response.